# Not able to install and run kettle from CE 4.0.1

Tags: pentaho

I downloaded the CE edition of PDI 4.0.1 and extracted in Data Integration folder. 
When I click spoon.bat, it says 'could not find the main class' which i think is because i have Java 1.4 (I will install 1.5 for this)

But if i have to create my scripts using spoon and run them through spoon, I need kettle.properties file. How will it get created based on this installation, as I think it only gets created if you run the installer ?. Also what about the license

I am really confused as to what is the right way to install kettle 4.0.1 on a fresh windows system

Thanks
David

Comment: If I remember correctly, the .properties file is created the first time you run Spoon. Fix the Java version issue and see if that gets you running. If it does it should create the .properties file. BTW, you might want to consider upgrading. There are many important bugs that have been fixed since the 4.0.1 version.

Comment: I prefer to use java 1.6 or higher.. if you use 1.5 their is possibility that you may face problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

You should use java 1.6 or higher and set environment variable **%JAVA_HOME%** to the java directory.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

ok, so when installing pentaho kettle PDI you need JRE 7 
but also to make the variable environment means JAVA HOME to direct to your java installation

your kettle.properties is at the user folder under .kettle
but its not connected to the first install of kettle

for more information you can go to my webite [pentaho kettle tutorial course](http://pentahokettletutorial.com) there is a video on the course that show you how to install it and of course master pentaho kettle